# How to cancel multiple request service with foreach in angular 7?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to cancel multiple request service with foreach in angular 7.

```
   this.attachmentList.forEach(email => {
   this._attachmentHttpService.getEmailAttachments(email.id).takeUntil(this.unsubscribe).subscribe((data: any) => {
    email.date = this.dateService.getUtcStringDate(new Date(data.date));
    const byteArray = new Uint8Array(atob(data.content).split('').map(char => char.charCodeAt(0)));
    const blob = new Blob([byteArray], {type: 'application/pdf'});
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    email.pdfSrc = url;
    email.content = url;
    email.attachementMailName = data.attachementMailName;
    email.blob = blob;
    email.subject = data.subject;

  });     
});
```

I tried this solution: but I didn't succeeded

```
 serve: Array<any>;
this.attachmentList.forEach(email => {
 const test=  this._attachmentHttpService.getEmailAttachments(email.id).takeUntil(this.unsubscribe).subscribe((data: any) => {
    email.date = this.dateService.getUtcStringDate(new Date(data.date));
    const byteArray = new Uint8Array(atob(data.content).split('').map(char => char.charCodeAt(0)));
    const blob = new Blob([byteArray], {type: 'application/pdf'});
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    email.pdfSrc = url;
    email.content = url;
    email.attachementMailName = data.attachementMailName;
    email.blob = blob;
    email.subject = data.subject;       
  });
 this.serve.push(test);
});
this.serve.foreach(data=>{data.unsubscribe()});
```

which best solution for that ?

Comment: `.takeUntil(this.unsubscribe)` - what's "this.unsubscribe"?

Comment: @mbojko it 's  private unsubscribe = new Subject<void>();

Comment: Then simply making it emit should cause all the still-alive subscriptions to be canceled: `this.unsubscribe.next()`

Comment: @mbojko sorry i didn't get your answer can u explain for me : this.unsubscribe.next() i will put it here :  this.serve.foreach(data=>{this.unsubscribe.next()});

Comment: No need for `forEach`. Simply: every of the subscriptions goes through the `takeUntil` operator, which unsubscribes as soon as `this.unsubscribe` emits. Hence, executing `this.unsubscribe.next()` _once_ should cease them all.

Comment: you can try test forkJoin https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin

Comment: @mbojko  it works with this.unsubscribe.next() .thanks for our help :)

Comment: @Moslem Shahsavan thanks for your help :)